# How to replace method 'combineLatest' from rxJs with a not deprecated method?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6, ngrx-effects, combinelatest

I implemented method using `combinlatest` rsjx/operator one, it work properly but sonar issue given said it deprecated.so , I need to convert it latest one. but I try, just replace import it gave error. I need some expert help to do this .

```
gX$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionType.A),
    combineLatest(this.service.getoc()),
    mergeMap(([, oc]) => this.reviewService.findBy(oc.id,
      new Date(),
      new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1)))
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(d => {
          return of(reviewLoadSuccess({ reviews: getReviews(d) }));
        }
        ),
        catchError(error => {
          return of(reviewLoadFailure({ error: error }));
        })
      )
    )));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems that you only need the value returned by `this.service.getoc()`, I would recommend of using `switchMapTo` operator instead, as demonstrated below

```js
 gX$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(ActionType.A),
   switchMapTo(this.service.getoc()),
   mergeMap(oc => this.reviewService.findBy(oc.id,
     new Date(),
     new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1)))
     .pipe(
       mergeMap(d => {
         return of(reviewLoadSuccess({ reviews: getReviews(d) }));
       }
       ),
       catchError(error => {
         return of(reviewLoadFailure({ error: error }));
       })
     )
   )));
```

Consider applying the following changes, should you want to use the action as well :

```js
gX$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(ActionType.A),
    switchMap(action => this.service.getoc().pipe(
      switchMap(oc => {
        //  you have access to both action, and oc
        // ... continue running your code
      })
    ))
  )
)
```

Comment: I will try this, actually, code used ''rxjs/operators'; - combinelatest , it will give sonarissue it was deprecated.thank you.

Comment: @Rafi Henig There is a difference between `combineLatest` from `rxjs` and `rxjs/operators`. The operators one is indeed deprecated.

Comment: `withLatestFrom` leads to different behaviour than `combineLatest`.

Comment: `@fridoo`  had the have to use source, using `withLatastFrom` would have been the right choice, provided that the second Observable has already emitted once, what doesn't seem to happen in his context, so technically your are correct.

Comment: I tried withlatestfrom , but in this situation ,it not work. but switchmapto work.this effect call inside , ngOnIniteffect .

Answer (score 5):

You need to import from `rxjs` not `rxjs/oeprators` and use it like this:

```js
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

combineLatest([
  this.actions$.pipe(ofType(ActionType.A)),
  this.service.getoc()
]).pipe(mergeMap(...));
```

Comment: Wow, that was it! Angular allows you to import either the rxjs or the rxjs/operators, one is deprecated the other isn't